# Possible to per file encrypt cloud storage?

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage, encryption, cloud

With the many cloud storage providers that there now exist, would it be possible to add a layer of encryption before the files are saved?

It would be possible to make an encrypted partition in a file, but having to sync a 5GB file when only 5kB have changed is not optimal.

Ideally would I like to have per file encryption and file names and directory names encrypted.

Would something like that be possible?

**Update**

[EncFS](http://www.arg0.net/encfs) might just be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) with [python-cloudfiles](http://packages.python.org/python-cloudfiles/) is another tool with good encryption support. It supports [gnugpg](http://www.gnupg.org/) out of the box, and works with most* openstack providers object storage.

It uses rsync like semantics, [so is really](http://27smiles.com/2010/04/07/securely-backup-of-vps-with-duplicity-and-gpg/) easy to add to [existing scripts](http://blog.chmouel.com/2009/09/02/rsync-like-backup-to-rackspace-cloud-file-with-duplicity/);

```
 $ duplicity ~/mystuff/important/data cf+http://my-full-backup

 Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed. Last full backup date: none No signatures found, switching to full backup. 
--------------[ Backup Statistics ]-------------- 
StartTime 1329330905.94 (Wed Feb 15 18:35:05 2012) 
EndTime 1329330906.01 (Wed Feb 15 18:35:06 2012) 
ElapsedTime 0.07 (0.07 seconds) SourceFiles 2 
SourceFileSize 170871 (167 KB) NewFiles 2 
NewFileSize 170871 (167 KB) DeletedFiles 0 
ChangedFiles 0 ChangedFileSize 0 (0 bytes) 
ChangedDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes) DeltaEntries 2 
RawDeltaSize 166775 (163 KB) 
TotalDestinationSizeChange 155070 (151 KB) 
Errors 0 --------------------------
-----------------------
```

- currently I have tested with Rackspace and hpcloud.com object storage.

http://take-your-vitamins.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/howto-backup-to-object-store-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Sandra, your syncing solution would require me to know your OS and the cloud storage provider you are using. However gpg would be an excellent fit for your encryption needs.

There is a great tutorial on how to do this [here](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2007/08/16/encryption-files-with-gpg-without-user-intervention-batch/).

Answer (score 0):

Think of this in a slightly different way, how would you do this if it were on say a local shared disk? You could use encrypted ZIP, 7ZIP or as dc5553 suggests gpg/pgp etc. Basically don't think of it any differently than any other shared storage from this respect ok.